# equals not working as expected when used for a single property

Tags: java, set, equals, case-sensitive

I let IntelliJ generate the override for and have tried to use `equalsIgnoreCase` but it doesn't seem to be working correctly, case is being ignored when adding the object to a `Set`.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Player player = (Player) o;

    //return playerName.equals(player.playerName);
    return playerName.equalsIgnoreCase(player.playerName);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return playerName.hashCode();
}
```

```
//Adds Players with the name of "bob" and "Bob" but don't want it to
boolean added = setOfPlayers.add(new Player(playerName.trim()));
if (!added) {
    System.out.println("Player with the name " + playerName.trim() + " already exists");
    }
```

Basically just want to have a set with Players that have unique names ignoring case.

Comment: Your implementation of `hashCode` is not consistent with `equals`. Things that are considered equal by `equals` must have the same hash code.

Comment: ... a quick fix would be to call `playerName.toLowerCase(Locale.Root).hashCode()` in `hashCode()`.